# Does go-ethereum encrypt new wallets by default?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

And if so, is it considered safe to store and encrypted wallet on a unencrypted drive?

I know there is a process to lock and unlock accounts with a password, but how difficult is it to brute force the unlocking process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are encrypted, geth uses AES 128. AES is a good algorith for encryption, until quantum computers arrive it should be safe against brute force attacks.

More plausible attacks are using a malware, phishing, fake wallets.